# Modify JavaScript code to match a to b instead of a to a?

Tags: javascript, html

How to create a lamguage/vocabulary matching game, like the game below, so that instead of matching image a to itself, match image a to a word (or image b)?

Or, how to manipulate code for this game (link below) so that instead of matching a to a, it matches a to b?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="../../retour.js"></SCRIPT><STYLE type="text/CSS">.bouton { border-top-width:2;  border-bottom-width:2;  border-left-width:2px;  border-right-width:2;border-style:solid;border-color:#CCCCCC;width:46px;height:46px; background:#FFFFFF url(../../img/assoMemi/invisibl.gif) no-repeat center;}
.essai {  font-size:1em; font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;color:#FFFFFF;background:#0A3F8E;border-top-width:0;  border-bottom-width:0;  border-left-width:0px;  border-right-width:0}
#boutonImage0 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image1.gif);}
#boutonImage1 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image2.gif); }
#boutonImage2 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image3.gif); }
#boutonImage3 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image4.gif); }
#boutonImage4 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image5.gif); }
#boutonImage5 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image6.gif); }
#boutonImage6 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image7.gif); }
#boutonImage7 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image8.gif); }
#boutonImage8 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image9.gif); }
#boutonImage9 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image10.gif); }
#boutonImage10 {background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image11.gif); }
#boutonImage11 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image12.gif); }
#boutonImage12 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image13.gif);}
#boutonImage13 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image14.gif); }
#boutonImage14 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image15.gif); }
#boutonImage15 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image16.gif); }
#boutonImage16 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image17.gif); }
#boutonImage17 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image18.gif); }
#boutonImage18{ background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image19.gif); }
#boutonImage19 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image20.gif); }
#boutonImage20 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image21.gif); }
#boutonImage21 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image22.gif); }
#boutonImage22 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image23.gif); }
#boutonImage23 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image24.gif); }
#boutonImage24 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image25.gif); }
#boutonImage25 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image26.gif); }
#boutonImage26 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image27.gif); }
#boutonImage27 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image28.gif); }
#boutonImage28 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image29.gif); }
#boutonImage29 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image30.gif); }
#boutonImage30 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image31.gif); }
#boutonImage31 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image32.gif); }
#boutonImage32 { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image33.gif); }#boutonCarte { background-image:url(../../img/assoMemi/invisibl.gif); }</STYLE><BGSOUND ID="fondSon"><SCRIPT><!--

//Régine B-D ; 24/02/03 
//http://perso.wanadoo.fr/jeux.lulu/
//Tous droits réservés


var nbCartes=66;
//charger "gagné"
var gagnes = new Array(5);
for (i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    gagnes[i]= new Image;
    gagnes[i].src="../../img/gagne"+i+".gif";
}
//test=0 joueur a la main; =1 non
var test=1;
//etat=0 pas de carte reournée; =1 1 carte ; =2 2 cartes
var etat=0;
//numero des cartes sélectionnées
var retournees=new Array (-1,-1);
//numero des boutons sélectionnés
var selectiones=new Array (-1,-1);
var cartes = new Array(nbCartes);
var lesImages = new Array(nbCartes/2);
for (i=0; i<nbCartes/2; i++) {
    lesImages[i]= new Image;
    lesImages[i].src="../../img/assoMemi/cirque/image"+i+".gif";
}
var couleurBoutonD="#FFFFFF";
var bons=0;
var essais=0;
var nbFois=0;
var nbErreurs=0;
var nbTemps=0;

function depart0() {
    t1=setTimeout("rien()",1);
    t2=setTimeout("rien()",1);
    for (i=0; i<nbCartes; i++) {
        if (i<nbCartes/2) {
            cartes[i]=i;
        } else {
            cartes[i]=i-nbCartes/2+100;
        }
    }
    depart();
}

function rien() {
}

function depart() {
    test=1;
    clearTimeout(t1);
    clearTimeout(t2);
    document.Formu.Message.value="";
    for (i=0; i<nbCartes; i++) {
        boutonDepart(i);
    }
    for (i=0; i<=25; i++) {
        document.images["caseEr"+i].src="../../img/assoMemi/invisibl.gif";
    }
    nbErreurs=0
    melange();
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        retournees[i]=-1;
        selectiones[i]=-1;
    }
    //effacer tableau gagné
    for (i=0; i<=4; i++) {document.images["gagne"+i].src="../../img/assoMemi/invisibl.gif";}
    test=0;
    etat=0;
    bons=0;
    document.Formu.elements["secondes"].value="";
    essais=0;
    for (i=0; i<nbCartes; i++) {
        boutonMontre(i);
    }
    nbTemps=0
    t2=setTimeout("temps()",1500);
}

function temps() {
    nbTemps+=1;
    if (nbTemps<2) {sec=" seconde"} else {sec=" secondes"}
    document.Formu.elements["secondes"].value="Temps : "+nbTemps+sec;
    t2=setTimeout("temps()",1000);
}

function boutonDepart(x) {
        document.Formu.elements["base"+x].value="";
        document.Formu.elements["base"+x].style.visibility="visible";
        document.Formu.elements["base"+x].id="boutonCarte";
        document.Formu.elements["base"+x].style.backgroundColor=couleurBoutonD;
        document.Formu.elements["base"+x].style.borderColor="#CCCCCC";
}

function boutonCache(x) {
        document.Formu.elements["base"+x].style.borderColor="#CCCCCC";
}

function boutonMontre(x) {
        test=1;
        if (retournees[0]!=retournees[1]) {
            document.Formu.elements["base"+x].style.borderColor="#FF0000";
        }
        if (cartes[x]<100) {
            document.Formu.elements["base"+x].id="boutonImage"+cartes[x];
            test=0
        } else {
            document.Formu.elements["base"+x].id="boutonImage"+(cartes[x]-100);
            test=0;
        }
}

function boutonMontreBons(x) {
        document.Formu.elements["base"+x].style.borderColor="#FF0000";
}

function boutonDisparait(x) {
    document.Formu.elements["base"+x].style.visibility="hidden";    
}

function choix(x) {
    if (test==0 && x!=selectiones[0] && x!=selectiones[1]) {
        if (etat<2) {
            retournees[etat]=cartes[x]%100;
            selectiones[etat]=x;
            etat+=1;
            boutonMontre(x);
            if (etat==1) {          
                essais+=1;
                //document.Formu.elements["nbEssais"].value="Nombre d'essais : "+essais;
            }
            if (retournees[0]==retournees[1]) {
                test=1;
                boutonMontreBons(selectiones[0]);
                boutonMontreBons(selectiones[1]);
                bons+=1;
                //t1=setTimeout ("suite()",200);
                suite()
            } else {
                if (etat==2) {
                    document.images["caseEr"+nbErreurs].src="../../img/sequenti/non.gif";
                    nbErreurs+=1;
                    if (nbErreurs>25) {nbErreurs=25}
                }       
            }
        } else {
            etat=0;
            for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
                if (retournees[0]==retournees[1]) {
                    boutonDisparait(selectiones[i]);
                } else {
                    boutonCache(selectiones[i])
                }
            }
            for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
                retournees[i]=-1;
                selectiones[i]=-1;
            }
            choix(x);
        }
    } else {
        if (test==0 && (x==selectiones[0] || x==selectiones[1]) ) {
            boutonMontre(x);
        }
    }
}

function suite() {
        boutonDisparait(selectiones[0]);
        boutonDisparait(selectiones[1]);        
        if (bons==nbCartes/2) {
            clearTimeout(t2);
            gagnperd("gagne");
            nbFois+=1;
            document.Formu.Message.value=nbFois+" fois";
        } else {
            test=0;
        }
}

function melange() {
    for (i=0; i<nbCartes; i++) {
        n1=Math.floor(Math.random()*nbCartes);
        n2=Math.floor(Math.random()*nbCartes);
        while (n2==n1) {n2=Math.floor(Math.random()*nbCartes);}
        n=cartes[n1];
        cartes[n1]=cartes[n2];
        cartes[n2]=n;
    }
}

function gagnperd(x) {
    for (i=0; i<=4; i++) {
            document.images["gagne"+i].src=gagnes[i].src;
    }
}
//--></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var gs_d=new Date,DoW=gs_d.getDay();gs_d.setDate(gs_d.getDate()-(DoW+6)%7+3);
var ms=gs_d.valueOf();gs_d.setMonth(0);gs_d.setDate(4);
var gs_r=(Math.round((ms-gs_d.valueOf())/6048E5)+1)*gs_d.getFullYear();
var gs_p = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gs_p + "s.gstat.orange.fr/lib/gs.js?"+gs_r+"' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
//]]>
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#0A3F8E" onload="depart0();">
<P><FORM ACTION="" METHOD=POST name=Formu>
   <CENTER><A NAME=jeu></A><SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript><!--

var lignes = 6;
var colonnes = 11;  
document.write("<table bgcolor='' bordercolor='' ");
document.write("align=center border=0 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>");
for (i = 0; i < lignes; i++) {
    document.write("<TR>");
    for (j = 0; j < colonnes; j++) {
            document.write("<td><INPUT TYPE=button NAME=base"+(colonnes*i+j)+" VALUE='' class=bouton onmousedown='choix("+(colonnes*i+j)+");'></td>");
    }
    document.write("</TR>");
}
document.write("</table>");


//--></SCRIPT>
```

[2 par 2](http://jeux.lulu.pagesperso-orange.fr/html/assoMemo/aCirque1.htm)

Comment: Is the game in the link your game, and are you planning on modifying it? It would be a lot easier to answer the question if you could post the code you are trying to modify here or in a jsFiddle

Comment: Edit shows code now...

Comment: @LcLk - any ideas on how I can: 1) match image to word and 2) record how many errors are made whilst clicking?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help. You never said if this is your code, and the code you pasted in is straight from the website you mentioned. I'm also having a hard time following it as I don't speak French.
My advice is not to copy the code, but write your own implementation. You will learn a lot by doing this. If you then still have a problem with getting words to match images, ask a new question, and follow the SO guidelines by creating an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is an easy way.

Assign a special id or number to your image/word.
Then, compare both of the id when image/word is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
that's where i'm having the issue, can't seem to make it work

Comment: Hi all,

Thanks to  @Dexter Cheong Hon Sang, I've figured out how to match image A to image B, now I can't figure out how to match image A to a word, as I can't write them into CSS (unlike the images) and I'm having problems writing it into javascript, and I can't do it in html as the word's meant to sit inside the button.

ANy ideas of codings that make it possible? @LcLK? @karel?
 
ALSO, how could I modify this so that when a wrong match is clicked, the number of errors are counted and displayed on screen as they happen?

Help is appreciated.